# Pass different types into function

Tags: swift, function, core-data, types

I'm trying to save to diffrent core data objects based on what list they want to save it to.

Is it possible to make a function which you pass in a type and it save to the correct list based on that?

```
 let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    if index == 0 {
        let task = TodayTask(context: context)

        task.name = taskText.text! // Do this in function insead
        task.adress = addressField.text // Do this in function insead
        task.date = userDate // Do this in function insead

    }else if listIndex.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
        let task = WeekTask(context: context)
        task.name = taskText.text!
    }else {
        let task = Task(context: context)
        task.name = taskText.text!

func saveToCoreData(task: SomeList){
    let task = SomeList(context: context) // The correct list based on what the user chooses
    task.name = taskText.text!
    task.adress = addressField.text
    task.date = userDate
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a technique called dynamic dispatch. For example:

```
func accept(value: String) {
    //This to process a string
}

func accept(value: Int){
    //This called to process an Int
}
```

Then you just call accept(value: myValue) and the function will dynamically dispatch to the correct function.

Comment: I tried what you said but I don't seem to get it to work, I get an error Cannot convert value of type TodayTask.Type to exptected argument type TodayTask

Comment: Never mind I rewrote the function and now its working! Thanks!